# How to solve replication Errors in CloudSQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

In RDS its possible to use mysql.rds_skip_repl_error. In MySQl on prem I have ways to do that to but requires super privileges.  Usually, how can I skip some replication errors in Cloud SQL? I tried to found anything in docs and forums, but I didn't found anything. =/

Answer (score 0):

As of now the usage of `slave-skip-errors` and other alternatives to skip errors are not supported in Cloud SQL for MySQL.

There is already a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/128603238) where other users have asked for this.

The only mentioned work around so far is to do the following Steps:

- Create a Compute Engine Instances
- Intall MySQL server on it
- Set the flag `--slave-skip-errors` on this MySQL installation.